# Unable to copy link when long pressing in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiactionsheet

The sharing action sheet comes up, I can select Open, Add to Reading List, Copy, Share.. but none of the buttons work. For instance, when I tap copy, Pasteboard does not receive the URL.

The URL is correctly displayed in the action sheet. Any ideas? Perhaps I forgot to implement a delegate or so..?

Answer (score 0):

Please add some code snippets for better understanding of your problem. Also if you are trying to select text in a webview make sure

> document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout

is not equal to "none".